Can we have a general formula for this sequence?
Consider a sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $a_n \in (0,1)$ each. In detail, $(a_n)_n$ is given by a "recurrence" relation:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n \sqrt{a_n^2+4} - a_n^2}{2}.$$
Note that since we restricted the sequence to be inside $(0,1)$, we must have $(a_n)_n$ strictly decreasing. Also, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$ regardless of choice of $a_0$.
My question is: can we express such $a_n$ is a general formula form? I want to do that and then do some asymptotic analysis on $a_n$ (as a function of $n \in \mathbb{N}$). Say, if it is $a_n \in \mathcal{O}(1/n)$ or $a_n \in \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$, etc..

You can re-write you formula as
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac2{1+\sqrt{1+4/a_n^2}}
$$
which ensures that whatever $a_0$ is, $0<a_1<1$, and then $0<a_2<\frac2{1+\sqrt 5}=0.618\dots$
For smaller $a_n$, we have $4/a_n^2\gg 1$ so
$$
a_{n+1}\approx \frac{2a_n}{2+a_n}\approx a_n(1-a_n/2)
$$
which roughly corresponds to the equation $y'=-y^2/2$ so asymptotically
$$
a_n\asymp \frac{C}n.
$$
(Needless to say, there's no exact explicit formula).
P.S. If you set $b_n=a_n n$, then
$$
b_{n+1}=b_n\left(1+\frac{2-b_n}{2n}\right)+O(1/n^2)
$$
from which you conclude that $b_n\to 2$ (and hence $C=2$).

But you get $$\frac1{a_{n+1}}\approx \frac12+\frac1{a_n},$$ which can be easily continued.

$a_n=\frac{2}{\sinh c_n}$ leads to $\sinh c_{n+1}=\sinh^2 c_{n}\sinh \frac{c_n}{2}.$ Using $c\leq \sinh c\leq e^c$ we get $c_{n+1}\geq 3 \log c_n.$
